# Manual case creation with validation on 6 lookup fields

Tags: lightning, force.com, case, lookup

I need to create manual cases where 'case type' is 'Manual'
I have 6 lookup fields on Case as

- Lookup_MTO (object is MTO)
- Lookup_Re (object is Re)
- Lookup_ToP (object is ToP)
- Lookup_Bk (object is Bk)
- Lookup_To (object is To)
- Lookup_Ld (object is Ld)

My requirement is If Lookup_To is populated by User on the New case UI, only Lookup_MTO  related to that Lookup_To should appear as available options on Lookup_To field. Same with Lookup_Re , Lookup_ToP , Lookup_Bk and Lookup_Ld. 
Likewise user can populate any  lookup filed not only Lookup_To ,in any case rest of the lookups should come up with values related to that Lookup field populated by user.

Relationship between objects is :

- Re(child) is having Lookup to MTO(parent)
- To,ToP,Bk,Ld is having many to many relationship with MTO
- Bk is child to ToP (look up relationship)
- To is a child to ToP (look up relationship)

How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are [Lookup Filters](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/10/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_filtered_lookups_cheatsheet.pdf). This will cause the UI to only show related records based on the criteria. You don't need to use "validation" for this, as the system will enforce it for you. Just go in to the fields that should be filtered and specify the criteria.

Comment: Lookup filter will work if lookup on case are related to each other as parent child
ex:If the value of a relationship field should depend on the value of another relationship field on the current record, specify the field to field comparison in the criteria. For example, if the case Contact Name field should only have contacts associated to the account specified in the case Account Name field, use the following lookup filter:

Filter Criteria
Contact Name: Account ID equals field Case: Account ID

Answer (score 0):

@sfdcfox
Lookup filter will work if lookup on case are related to each other as parent child
ex:If the value of a relationship field should depend on the value of another relationship field on the current record, specify the field to field comparison in the criteria. For example, if the case Contact Name field should only have contacts associated to the account specified in the case Account Name field, use the following lookup filter:

Filter Criteria
Contact Name: Account ID equals field Case: Account ID

In my case if user enters Lookup_ToP and if I want to validate values in all 5 fields should be related to Lookup_Top then in need all other objects to be child of Lookup_ToP.
For ex if user populate Look_Top=12345
now next he went to Lookup_MTO field than in that case Lookup_MTO should have lookup to Lookup_ToP so that I can validate
Lookup_MTO:Lookup_TOP:ID =Case: Lookup_ToP:ID